# jQuery datepicker dateformat and SQL Server date format

Tags: jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, datetimepicker

In my database I store dates in the form, where days and months don't have prefixed zeroes.

Examples:

```
1.4.2014 0:00:00
26.4.2014 0:00:00
```

I have an edit form with a jQuery datepicker, where I want to change the date.

The date format of the datepicker is set like this:

```
dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy 0:00:00'
```

This gives me client side validation errors, on the form, because the date is not in the same format like in the db (without prefixed zeros).

And if I change the datepicker format like this, I am unable to pick dates with the month and day higher than 9, since the format specifies only one digit for the day and month:

```
dateFormat: 'd.m.yy 0:00:00'
```

Does anybody know a solution?

Comment: No. They are stored as DateTime objects.

Answer (score 0):

You should always have a service model between your view and db model, to avoid any such conflicts.

```
dateFormat: 'd.m.yy 0:00:00'
```

will never work for you. Instead you could use a date parsing js like Date.js or Moment.js to convert the selected date to the format you require to set.

And I dont recommend you to show date in this format - `26.4.2014 0:00:00` to the user. Make it more user friendly bring that data to your server code, to your service model and then convert it to the required format which your db demands.